# Какие есть приемы привлечения внимания аудитории?

Tags: риторика

Какие есть приемы привлечения внимания аудитории?

Answer (score 1):

Обращение к аудитории с риторическим вопросом; не читать свой доклад, а рассказывать с интонацией; приводить примеры из жизни, если они уместны к исходной теме; уважение к аудитории за то, что она собирается выслушать вас.

Если аудитория не слушает вас и вы не можете привлечь внимание, то это будет только ваша вина. Поэтому нужно много выступать, чтобы уже вы смогли приемлемое для аудитории поведение, и, поверьте мне, у вас получится, нужно только постараться.

Answer (score 0):

Например, употребление слова "пожалуйста" при обращении с просьбой.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть время и желание, почитайте  "Камасутра для оратора", автор Р. Гандапас. В интернете есть. По теме, интересно написано, читается на одном дыхании.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, Вас интересуют языковые средства привлечения внимания слушателей. Рискуя оказаться бесполезной, подойду к решению вопроса с позиции психологии. Самый верный, на мой взгляд, способ заставить аудиторию слушать вас раскрыв рот - строить речь таким образом, чтобы логическая связь каждой последующей мысли с предшествующей выявлялась не в первый момент.

Не самый лучший, конечно, пример использования этого приема, но все же это лучше, чем никакого: *"Читатель! Исторический роман — особая форма романа: в нем рассказывается не то, что логично выдумано, а то, что нелогично было. 
Следовательно, стройная архитектоника у нас вряд ли получится. В череде знакомств на протяжении всей нашей жизни одни люди возникают, другие уходят.
Так же и в историческом романе автор вправе вводить новых героев до самого конца романа. Это нелогично с точки зрения литературных канонов, но зато логично в историческом плане. У меня нет композиции, а есть хронология. Ибо я не следую за своим вымыслом, а лишь придерживаюсь событий, которые я не в силах исправить…" (В. Пикуль. Нечистая сила).*
Поначалу создается впечатление, что предложение *"В череде знакомств на протяжении всей нашей жизни одни люди возникают, другие уходят"* не продолжает уже начатую мысль, а начинает новую, никак не связанную со сказанным ранее, что заставляет слушателя, заинтригованного и решившего, что он отвлекся и что-то пропустил, поэтому не видит связи, слушать с особым вниманием.

Answer (score 0):

[@МАША](/users/332/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0). Надо иметь в активе книжку приличных анекдотов - желательно, относящихся к излагаемой теме. Начать с самого весёлого. От него плавно перейти к материалу. Материал излагать энергично, выразительно, следя за глазами слушателей - понимают ли они, от чём идёт речь? Аудитория, как правило, разномастная по всем параметрам, и всем не угодишь, как говорится. Когда глаза становятся скучающими, отвлечёнными, надо привлечь себе на помощь шутку или новый анекдот. Можно использовать истории из жизни известных людей по данной специальности или политиков. Если у Вас нелегко с речью, с её плавностью, округлостью, надо сначала тренироваться с выступлением дома. Не сразу, постепенно Вы обретёте необходимую лёгкость общения с аудиторией, и это окрылит Вас! Мой совет покажется Вам старомодным, но это будет потом, потом. А пока... Начните читать сначала.